# Junction box down-sizing when using oversized conduit

Tags: electrical, conduit, junction-box

I'm running 4 x 4AWG copper wires through 1-1/4"conduit. I have 6 elbows in the 125' run so I need to insert a junction box before the last two elbows. It will be a straight pull through the junction box. By code, I could have used 1" conduit (~38% fill) but chose to go up a size to 1-1/4" (resulting in ~22% fill). 314.28(A)(1) states that the junction box must be 8 times the size of the conduit for straight pulls, or 10" in this case. However, if I am interpreting 314.28(A)(3) correctly, I can use a smaller junction box if I am less than the maximum conduit fill (which I am). Since, I could have used 1" conduit does this imply that I could use an 8" junction box even though I used 1-1/4" conduit?

Comment: Beware the false economy. Using larger conduit gives you options in the future. Considering the **total** cost of the job, is the **tiny percentage savings** in cheaping out on the junction box sensible? Also, if possible, consider if you can put it where there's 270 degrees of bend on either side rather than 360 & 180. 360 is to code, but miserable to pull in practice, not unlike 40% fill.

Comment: If the pull box is being set in a fairly straight section of conduit. A neat little trick is to use a 4x4x24 wireway for ease of pull. Remember you have to pull the conductors out of one end and into the other. Manhandling larger conductors in a small box can cause problems and add to frustration and damage to the conductors.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, my issue isn't based on cost savings it is a two fold issue. (1) I have space restrictions where the junction box will be going and (2) I cannot find the 10" box in stock around me. 

As far as the pull goes, its already been pulled through to where the junction box is going and from the junction box to the subpanel is only another 8 feet. The last 2 elbows are just getting it to the panel.

@ RetiredMasterElectrician, the junction box is in fact in a long straight stretch so I will have a look at the wireway you mentioned.

Comment: Also, for what its worth, I don't see any future changes. This project is running a subpanel to the basement (main panel is in the garage). The subpanel is already oversized for what will be in the basement so I do not foresee any changes (though I definitely understand and agree with the future proofing concept).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Don't worry about it. Just use the [standard C-type conduit body](https://www.bptfittings.com/store/1-1-4-combination-type-c-conduit-body.html), which is designed to exclusively be an access point for pulling in a straightline section.   *That is literally its one purpose, so obviously, UL wouldn't list it if it couldn't comply with Code*.  As far as your frustration finding the right thing, the caliber of your work is beyond the local big-box store (which, ironically, doesn't do well stocking big boxes) -- you need the real electrical supply.

You can use C-type conduit bodies anywhere they will remain accessible.   However, the better plan, generally, is to use LB, LL or LR conduit bodies as access points instead.  That lets you kill 2 birds with one stone: it eliminates one of your four allowed 90 bends while also creating an access point.  *However, when you do this, you must use the access point to pull - you are not allowed to drag wires around conduit body corners even if that is feasible*.  They're not made for it and will damage the insulation.  The only corners you can drag around are sweeps that have typically a 6-12" radius.

Also, the first rule of conduit is that **the conduit route must be finished before you start pulling wire through it**.  That's not a Harper Rule, that's actual Code.  I mention that because it sounds like you are building the conduit over top of the wires. That's not allowed. It's too easy to leave a conduit route that is unpullable.

Once somebody used one of these to go around an inside corner - the cover was facing the wall and could not be removed. Can't do that! And obeying the "pull the wire after construction is complete" rule takes care of that!

[image: outside corner pulling elbow]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I did look at an LR initially but figured the junction box provides more space for getting at the wires which is why I was going that way. I also wasn't sure about the sizing because an LR is much smaller than the required dimensions of the junction box (but maybe I'm using a junction box in the wrong application here....I just know I spoke with the local inspector and he said I could use either one). Yeah I did see the code about prebuilding all conduit but since I didnt have my box, and my help was here we just pulled the 95% that was ready (continued below)

Comment: I figured it would be easy enough to pull the last few feet once the LR/box was installed. To clarify, when you say "you are not allowed to drag wires around conduit body corners even if that is feasible" are you saying I need to pull all of the wire through one end of the LR first and then feed it back in the other hole and not try to pull the wire through both LR holes at the same time?

Comment: @Brad That works, but you're also allowed to have like 6' of it looping out of the LR while you're pulling.You might have a 6' balloon/bubble at access point A, pull in 30', then go to access point B and pull that 30' along leaving the 6' bubble at A, etc.   What you can't do is pull from access point B in a way that drags wire around the corner at point A...

Comment: When you're at "B" you just have to be sensitive to when the drag force increase, because that means the wires at A are starting to tangle up and you need to go deal with that. One reason I like to keep it down to one 90 is the pulling force around several gets quite large, and can obscure that subtle signal...